# Shiny app deployment error on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am facing error while trying to deploy shiny app to shinyapps.io. Please suggest the workaround

```
deployApp(appName = "tweethunt")
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 102109...DONE
Deploying bundle: 451828 for application: 102109 ...
Waiting for task: 181773387
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 444041
  building: Installing system dependencies
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
[2016-05-15T05:46:13.400250769+0000] Execute script: packages/build/tm.sh
+ set -e
+ apt-get update -qq
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 14288 14289
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 165433 165443
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 4853 4855
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_source_Sources.gz is not what the server reported 143399 143405
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 165433 165443
W: Failed to fetch http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 181773388 failed: Error building image: Build exited with non-zero status: 100
```